# Sending notifications to android application

Tags: php, android

I am developing an Android app which consumes an API I have written in PHP.

There are 2 types of users of the app, admin and regular user.

An admin can call a specific endpoint of the API which is basically a message which is tied to a specific user.

At this point I need to send a notification from the server (I presume) to the user's app. Even if the user doesn't have the app open at that time.

Is this called push notifications? I don't understand how I put code in the API to send messages down to a specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebase Push Notifications. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/) the source with guides.
And complete [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) with backend. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use push notifications to notify users even when they didn't have app opened at that time. You can refer this to understand how to make a firebase push notifications enabled application - http://www.androidlearning.in/android-push-notifications-using-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-php-mysql/

Also you can refer firebase.google.com for more info

Also you can refere YouTube for vedio tuto ... A simple example is here - https://youtu.be/LiKCEa5_Cs8 I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes @andrewb you are right you will have to send push notification to users. For that you can use different-different type of services 1) **GCM** (Google Cloud Messaging).  2) **FCM** (Firebase Cloud Messaging). 3) **SNS** (Simple Notification service which provided by Amazon). I think you can choose any service from above, each services is easy to integrate. The key point is to send notification - we have to get device token of individuals user when they install our app. Store that device tokens in database and then populate this token to respective service like(GCM,FCM,SNS).

Here I am giving you some links which can help you to integrate-

1) Using [GCM](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-using-gcm-tutorial/)

2) Using [FCM](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

3) Using [SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html)

SNS is little tricky, so you should go with above two. These articles are very clearly written and easy to understandable. I think this might be help you to understand better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can send push notifications to mobile app using GCM,FCM,SNS etc.

I recommend to go with GCM. You can write PHP scripts in the server end and configure with Google Cloud Messaging. 
Follow the below link

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-multicast-push-notifications-using-gcm/

Hope it will help you :-)